# How many permutations of six letters $a,b,c,d,e,f$ with the following placement restrictions?

Tags: combinatorics

I am doing some discrete problems out of a textbook, and am struggling on this question:

**How many ways are there to arrange the letters $a, b, c, d, e, f$ such that
$a$ is not directly followed by either $b$ or $c$? For example, “$abdef c$” and “$acdef b$” are
both invalid, but “$adbcef$” is valid.**

Immediately looking at the problem, I can tell we are using the difference method. We can subtract the total cases from the invalid cases. So, the answer should be something like $6! - $(# of invalid cases). I am having a tough time figuring a way to find invalid cases.

The only progress I made to the problem was manually finding out the number of correct cases where $a$ is in each place. For example, suppose $a$ is placed in the first slot.

$b,c$ cannot follow, thus giving us ($5-2$)  $3$ choices of letters. Then since we are not directly following $a$ anymore, we have $4$ letters, then $3$ ...

If $a$ is in the last slot, then we permute as normal with $5!$ total valid cases. How do I go about finding the invalid cases? Thanks.

Comment: To get half the invalid cases "glue" $a$ and $b$ together to make "one" card.  Now you have five cards.  How many ways can you arrange them?  Repeat for gluing $a$ and $c$.  Can you continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both forbidden cases can be handled by treating `ab` or `ac` as one block, then permuting the $5!$ "letters" that remain. These cases do not overlap, so the answer is $6!-2\cdot5!=480$ ways.

Answer (score 1):

You condition on whether $a$ is in the last slot.  If it is in the last slot you have $5!$ ways to arrange the rest.  If not, you have $5$ choices for the slot of $a$, $3$ choices for the next letter, and $4!$ ways to order the rest.

Answer (score 0):

**Another method**

$a$ is equally likely to be directly followed in $(0\;thru\;5) = 6$ ways

Thus valid ways $= \dfrac46\cdot 6!=480$